# How to update background location of user within specific time interval using swift 4 iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, core-location

I am working on an app. where I am updating a background location of a user. and I want to update that location within a specific time interval. I have searched a lot. but did not get any solution. please help me out. Here my code below. Thanks in advance.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        self.labelLat.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        self.labelLongi.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        DataBaseFunctions.sharedInstance.saveUserDetail(dataToInsert: userLocation)
    }
```

Comment: what is your last time interval?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint  my location is updating every second. but I want to update it after every 10 minutes.

Comment: you need to set `Timer` for 10 minutes and when it get completed call `startUpdatingLocation()` and you will get location `OR` store user location in `didUpdateLocations ` and pass latest user location when timer get completed. May it help you

Comment: performFetchWithCompletionHandler is the right way to perform certain operation at regular interval. Also startMonitoringSignificantChange is the right way to update backend at regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Swift-NOW, 
You can use Timer for didUpdateLocation with

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func updateLocation() {
    let location: CLLocation = locationManager.location
    // Your code
}
```

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Tagged language is SWIFT. Write your code in Swift too please.

Comment: Yes I should do this

Comment: @Deevakar Does this answer helps u?